# pandas timedelta in hours errors out for timedelta64

Tags: pandas

I am able to take time difference  in hours between two timestamps. 
In my program t1 , and t2 are extracted from dataframe.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> t1='2017-08-06 02:00:00+00:00'
>>> t2='2017-08-07 02:00:00+00:00'
>>> t1=pd.Timestamp(t1)
>>> t2=pd.Timestamp(t2)
>>> delta=t2-t1
>>> print delta
1 days 00:00:00
>>> print delta.astype('timedelta64[h]')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Timedelta' object has no attribute 'astype'
```

Please tell me how to fix this .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is clear there is no method `astype` for `pd.Timestamp`, if you want the total hours then you need to call `.total_seconds` and divide:

```
In[79]:
delta.total_seconds()/3600

Out[79]: 24.0
```

or use `to_timedelta64` to convert the type to a `np.timedelta64` which does have the method `astype`:

```
In[82]:
delta.to_timedelta64().astype('timedelta64[h]')

Out[82]: numpy.timedelta64(24,'h')
```

Thanks to @Bharath, for the first case you can just do:

```
In[84]:
delta/pd.Timedelta(hours=1)

Out[84]: 24.0
```

Comment: or `delta/pd.Timedelta(hours=1)`

Comment: @Bharathshetty for the first case this is true but I wasn't sure if the OP wanted some scalar calculation or really a type conversion, thanks though I will add this